# Does assigning a user a default database in SQL Server give them permissions to that database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Just like the title says, does assigning a user a default database in SQL Server give them permissions to that database? Does it give the user read/write privileges? Full admin? None?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't give them any privileges on that database.

```
CREATE LOGIN [Foo] WITH PASSWORD=N'foo', 
                    DEFAULT_DATABASE=[AdventureWorks2012], 
                    DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[British], 
                    CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, 
                    CHECK_POLICY=OFF
```

Then logging in with those credentials gives the error message

> Cannot open user default database. Login failed. Login failed for user
>   'Foo'.

Comment: There is a difference between a user and a login that is probably worth pointing out. Your example creates a login, but it does not create a database user, which is the reason why you see the error message.

Comment: @zespri - True but you can only assign a default database to a login.

Answer (score 1):

No you have to explicitly give the permission to that database. Else it would have no priveleges.

You may also want to check [CREATE USER.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx)

> Creating a user grants access to a database but does not automatically
>   grant any access to the objects in a database. After creating a user,
>   common actions are to add users to database roles which have
>   permission to access database objects, or grant object permissions to
>   the user.

Also check the [CREATE LOGIN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx).

Comment: what is "readonly mode" as far as sql server is concerned, may I ask? I mean, read permission *is* a permission, right?

Comment: @zespri:- Updated my answer. I meant the read permission! Sorry for the misleading words :)

Answer (score 1):

To start with in SQL Server there are users and there are logins. Roughly speaking, logins are server-level and users are database level. You need to map a user to a login to allow a user connecting to the database with particular login credentials.

It is the logins that are assigned default database, not users.

Now when we got this out of the way let's deal with permissions. Each user in database by default is assigned ['public' database role](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx). You can't remove the role or remove users from the role. If a user is not assigned any explicit permissions in the database it will have the permission given to the public role. What these permissions are, obviously is different in each case - they are what has been granted. To check them you can run [this script](http://basitaalishan.com/2013/04/04/the-public-role-do-not-use-it-for-database-access/):

```
WITH [PublicRoleDBPermissions]
AS
(SELECT p.[state_desc] AS [PermissionType]
       ,p.[permission_name] AS [PermissionName]
       ,USER_NAME(p.[grantee_principal_id]) AS [DatabaseRole]
       ,CASE p.[class]
          WHEN 0 THEN 'Database::' + DB_NAME()
          WHEN 1 THEN OBJECT_NAME(major_id)
          WHEN 3 THEN 'Schema::' + SCHEMA_NAME(p.[major_id]) 
        END AS [ObjectName]
 FROM [sys].[database_permissions] p
 WHERE p.[class] IN (0, 1, 3)
        AND p.[minor_id] = 0)
SELECT [PermissionType]
      ,[PermissionName]
      ,[DatabaseRole]
      ,SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) AS [ObjectSchema]
      ,[ObjectName]
      ,o.[type_desc] AS [ObjectType]
      ,[PermissionType] 
            + ' ' + [PermissionName] 
            + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id])) 
            + '.' + QUOTENAME([ObjectName]) 
            + ' TO ' + QUOTENAME([DatabaseRole]) AS [GrantPermissionTSQL]
      ,'REVOKE'
            + ' ' + [PermissionName] 
            + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id])) 
            + '.' + QUOTENAME([ObjectName]) 
            + ' TO ' + QUOTENAME([DatabaseRole]) AS [RevokePermissionTSQL]
FROM [PublicRoleDBPermissions] p
JOIN [sys].[objects] o
    ON o.[name] = p.[ObjectName]
AND OBJECTPROPERTY(o.object_id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0
WHERE [DatabaseRole] = 'Public'
ORDER BY [DatabaseRole], [ObjectName], [ObjectType]
```

If nothing has been explicitly granted to the public role, there will be no permissions for the user. For example if I run this (the first part is borrowed [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19481965/284111)):

```
CREATE LOGIN [Foo] WITH PASSWORD=N'foo', 
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[AdventureWorks2012], 
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[British], 
CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, 
CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO

CREATE USER [Bar] FOR LOGIN [Foo]
GO
```

And then try to select from the database under the Foo login:

```
select * from person.address
```

I'll get

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Address', database
>   'AdventureWorks2012', schema 'Person'.

That's because the public role in my database does not have any extra permissions.